# Switch / Case in SQL Where clause with different ranges of numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, case, where-clause

I'd like to write a complex `SWITCH` statement with `SQL (SQL Server 2008 R2)`

The goal is to write something like this in a `WHERE` statement:

- If `myParam = 0`, then `myColumn = myColumn` (0 means "undefined", so we "ignore" the `WHERE` statement)
- If `0 < myParam < 6`, then `myColumn = myParam`
- If `myParam >= 6`, then `myColumn = [6 ; Infinity]`

So I wrote :

```
WHERE 
  h.MyColumn = CASE @MyParam
                 WHEN 0 THEN h.MyColumn
                 WHEN @MyParam > 0 AND @MyParam < 6 THEN @MyParam
                 WHEN @MyParam > 6 THEN /* ??? */
```

First, am I on the good way ?
If so, how can I wrote the third `WHEN` ? `@MyParam` can only be equal to 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6, and in the last case, I need to select datas when `h.MyColumn > 6`.

Any help apreciated !
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can express this much simpler:

```
WHERE @MyParam = 0 
OR (@MyParam BETWEEN 1 AND 5 AND h.MyColumn = @MyParam)
OR (@MyParam = 6 AND h.MyColumn > 6)
```

Comment: This will lead to Scan instead of Seek (for the second and third option) if there is an index on MyColumn (first key column). An `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` could be a simple but costly (it depends, yes) solution.

Comment: You can write it with complicated case but you have a lot of "it depends" in there to be complaining about it. If the rest of the query is sufficiently complex, the `IF` branching will lead to horrendously tedious code to maintain. I'll take the `RECOMPILE` lumps instead, thanks.

Comment: AaronBertrand : This is working thank you very much !
@BogdanSahlean : Could you tell me more about OPTION(RECOMPILE) ? I need the query be as fast as possible, can I improve it with this option ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean Ok I will google about this option and do some tests to find the best way for me. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one parameter, one easy way to get desired results could be to use a simple `IF ... ELSE ...` statement thus:

```
IF @myParam=0
BEGIN
    SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    WHERE myColumn=myColumn2 -- ?
-- or
    SELECT ...
    FROM ...
END
ELSE IF 0 < @myParam AND @myParam < 6
BEGIN
    SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    WHERE myColumn=@myParam
END
ELSE IF @myParam > 6
BEGIN
    SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    WHERE myColumn=6
END
```

Questions:

1) What should happens if @myParam is < 0 or = 6 ?

2) What should happens if @myParam is null ?

Note: You should read [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have ~10 parameters, so I can't use your solution. BTW, my bad, @myParam is <= 6 and not just <6. I just edit it.

Answer (score 0):

My Suggestion:

```
if (@myParam = 0)
Begin
    select * from table
    Where h.MyColumn = 0
End
Else if (@myParam between 1 and 5)
Begin
    select * from table
    Where (h.MyColumn between 1 and 5)
End
Else
Begin
    select * from table
    Where (h.MyColumn > 5)
End
```

Comment: The request is a little bit long and I have ~10 parameters, so it will no be very readable. BTW, Thank you for the formatting ;)